# Rails 4/ Factory Girl - has_many/has_many factory and defining different objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I'd  like to define a factory for a has_many/has_many relationship (which I think I got it right) but I don't know how then to define attributes for each objects of these created factory.

Here is the homepage, it's a list of cards of deals

We assume the homepage view below is for a SIGNED-IN user (note current_user comes from Devise).

```
<% @deals.each do |deal| %>
  @userdeal = UserDeal.where('user_id = ? AND deal_id = ?', current_user.id, deal.id).take

    <div>
      <div class="button">
        <% if @userdeal.number_of_clicks = 4 %>you reached the maximum clicks
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Basically if a user has for a specific deal (on the table user_deals, see below the models) a user_deal.number_of_clicks = 4 then, on the card a button will appear with a message like "you reached the maximum clicks". if nb of clicks  <4, no button appears.

So I want to use the factory on a Feature test where I'll check that if I create with fatcory girl one object @userdeal1 where the user reached 4 clicks, on this card he sees the button and its text, but for other deals he sees nothing.

Here's what I have so far

models

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :user_deals,           dependent:  :destroy
  has_many   :users,                through:    :user_deals
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_deals          
  has_many :deals,                through: :user_deals
end

class UserDeal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user,         :foreign_key => 'user_id'
  belongs_to :deal,         :foreign_key => 'deal_id'
end
```

And the structure of the table user_deal

```
# Table name: user_deals
#
#  id                 :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id            :integer
#  deal_id            :integer
#  number_of_clicks   :integer          default(0)
#  created_at         :datetime
#  updated_at         :datetime
```

So far I found how to create

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user_deal do
    association :user
    association :deal  

end
```

Following factorygirl ReadMe I created this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do

    sequence(:email) { |n| "person#{n}@example.com"}   
    password "vddfdf"
    password_confirmation "vddfdf"
      confirmed_at Time.now
      confirmation_token nil

    factory :superadmin do
      after(:create) {|user| user.add_role(:superadmin)}
    end

    after(:create) do |user|
      user.deals << FactoryGirl.create(:deal)
    end

    factory :user_with_deals do
      # used for defining user_deals
      transient do
        deals_count 5 
      end
      after(:create) do |user, evaluator|
        create_list(:deal, evaluator.deals_count, user: user)
      end
    end

  end
end
```

But now I don't know how to say 'ok of one of these created user_deals in the factory, I'd like one to have number_of_clicks =4, and the other one number_of_clicks=1). so I tried to put this inside the test directly , as below:

```
describe 'HP deal card features', :type => :feature do

    context "As signed-in USER" do
    let(:subject) { ApplicationController.new }

    before do       
      @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, :user_country_name => 'Germany') 
      @deal1   = FactoryGirl.build( :deal)
      @deal2  = FactoryGirl.build( :deal)
      @user_deal_with_max_of_clicks = FactoryGirl.build( :user_with_deals,
                                                            :user             => @user,
                                                            :deal             => @deal1,
:number_of_clicks => 4
                                                        ).save(validate: false)
      @user_deal_with_clicks_available = FactoryGirl.build( :user_with_deals,
                                                            :user             => @user,
                                                            :deal             => @deal2,
number_of_clicks => 1 # still has clicks
                                                        ).save(validate: false)
    it "the right behavior for the buttons telling him how many clicks he has left" do

      sign_in @user
      visit root_path
      # I'll find a way to test here if there is the text "you reached the maximum clicks" for the first card and not for the second   
    end
    after do
      visit destroy_user_session_path
    end

  end
```

But the test does not work and give me different type of errors according to the small change I try. I am pretty sure I don't manage to really create the 2 objects user_deals , one with number_of_clicks= 4 and the other one number_of_clicks= 1.

**EDIT**

After requests to post the errors:

If i leave inside the @user_deal_with_max_of_clicks " :user=> @user, and                                                                 :deal => @deal1", I get

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `user=' for #<User:0x0000000b4754e0>
```

and

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `deal=' for #<User:0x0000000b451568>
```

But I remove them out as follows:

```
@user_deal_with_max_of_clicks = FactoryGirl.build( :user_with_deals,                                                               
    :number_of_clicks => 4
                                                        ).save(validate: false)
```

then I get this error:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `number_of_clicks=' for #<User:0x0000000b46ce80>
```

EDIT 2

utilities.rb

```
include ApplicationHelper

def sign_in(user)
    visit new_user_session_path
    fill_in     I18n.t("formtastic.labels.user.email"),         with: user.email
    fill_in     I18n.t("formtastic.labels.user.password"),      with: user.password
    click_on    I18n.t("devise.sessions.login_page.login")  
end
```

Comment: Can you post the error(s) that it's giving you?

Comment: @mysmallidea see edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I'd advise you to use `let`. There is a great guide to write [cleaner and better specs](http://betterspecs.org/#let).

Secondly, it is vital to set up good factories. They will simplify the testing process enormously:

So starting off, your user factories can be restructured to

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "person#{n}@example.com" }

    password "vddfdf"
    password_confirmation "vddfdf"

    confirmed_at Time.now
    confirmation_token nil

    trait :superadmin do
      role :superadmin
    end

    trait :with_deals do 
      after(:create) do |user|
        create_list(:deal, 5, user: user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

[Traits](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/remove-duplication-with-factorygirls-traits) are nice way to selectively adjust factories. So if you want your user to be a superadmin, now just use

```
create(:user, :superadmin)
```

Want a superadmin with deals? Easy.

```
create(:user, :superadmin, :with_deals)
```

You have not posted your deal factories, but I'm sure you can adapt these tricks to them as well.

Finally, leading to the `user_deals`. In your current factories, you don't address your `number_of_clicks` column.

Again, you can easily set this up with traits:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user_deal do
    association :user
    association :deal

    trait :few_clicks do
      number_of_clicks 1
    end

    trait :many_clicks do
      number_of_clicks 4
    end
  end
end
```

Now to the spec itself, with the learnt tricks it's an easy task to set up your desired relations:

```
describe 'HP deal card features', :type => :feature do
  context "As signed-in USER" do
    let(:subject) { ApplicationController.new }
    let(:user) { create(:user, user_country_name: 'Germany')  }
    let(:deal1) { create(:deal) }
    let(:deal2) { create(:deal) }

    before do
      create(:user_deal, :few_clicks, user: user, deal: deal1)
      create(:user_deal, :many_clicks, user: user, deal: deal2)
    end

    it "tells the user how many clicks he has left" do
      sign_in user
      visit root_path
      # I'll find a way to test here if there is the text "you reached the maximum clicks" for the first card and not for the second
    end

    after do
      visit destroy_user_session_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion. Clearly I need to clean up things. will do. I will test now your suggestion on the app.

Comment: I get an error and the line on which the error is reported is not even inside the " it tells the user how many clicks he has left do" but inside the "before do": it's on the line "create(:user_deal, :few_clicks, user: user, deal: deal1)" => the error is: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
       Deal(#86165360) expected, got TrueClass(#14299980)

Comment: by the way can I use the save(validate:false) with your way of creating things (let(:deal1) { create(:deal ) } ? indeed I need to skip hard validates. That's why I was using: FactoryGirl.build() .save(validate: false) (indeed in my real app, I was adding other attributes such as dates that I need not to validate in tests)

Comment: what kind of validation do you want to skip? Why not set up valid factories?

Comment: worked. thanks you're a genius. And on top of it I have key advice to clean up all my test suite. cheers

Comment: I've been there as well, it helps so much to add more structure to tests. I'm glad I could help :)